# get character from stream c++

Tags: c++, file, stream, character

```
FILE *in_fp;   

 void getChar() 
     {
        if ((nextChar = getc(in_fp)) != EOF) 
        {
            if (isalpha(nextChar))
                charClass = LETTER;
            else if (isdigit(nextChar))
                charClass = DIGIT;
            else charClass = UNKNOWN;
        }
        else
            charClass = EOF;
    }
```

i want function equivalent function getc() in c++
i search but i am not find

Note
if i use FILE the compiler show me this error

```
source.cpp(47): error C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to open a file and read a character using C++ I/O mechanism. You can do that using I/O streams.

You could do something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
....
std::ifstream in;//an input file stream
char nextChar;

in.open("your_file_name");//open a file for reading
if(in)
{//if opened successfully
    in.get(nextChar);//read a character from the stream
    .....//your other code
}
```

Comment: sorry. i didn't get that, is that a question for clarification?

Comment: the code is not work good because the  'if ( in_fp.get(nextChar)!=EOF)' dosenot match the char with EOF because is int

Comment: `ifstream` has a `eof()` function. you can use that to check for end of file.

Comment: i use it but this message error   cpp(116): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>, overloaded-function)'

Comment: how do you use it in your code. BTW you can just say `if(in_fp.get(nextChar))` because it will return false if the read fails or probably `if(nextChar=in_fp.get())!=EOF)`

Comment: i do it but  i have run time error i do not know why :( :(